# Fasm: How to move a string in x and y direction

Tags: screensaver, fasm

I want to output a string say for example "hello", and I want to put that string into motion by moving it to x or y direction.   How to  do it using fasm ? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To create the illusion of a string moving, you write the string on a selected position and shortly after you fill the same place on the screen with an equal amount of space characters.
Having done that, you're ready to re-write the string at a position slightly to the left or to the right or above or below the current position.

Here you can find info about [the BIOS SetCursor function](http://www.ablmcc.edu.hk/~scy/CIT/8086_bios_and_dos_interrupts.htm#int10h_02h).

Example starting from the middle of the 80x25 textscreen:

```
 mov  dx, 0C28h ;Row in DH is 12, Column in DL is 40
 call ShowString
 mov  dx, 0D29h ;Row in DH is 13, Column in DL is 41
 call ShowString
 mov  dx, 0E2Ah ;Row in DH is 14, Column in DL is 42
 call ShowString
 mov  dx, 0F2Bh ;Row in DH is 15, Column in DL is 43
 call ShowString

---

ShowString:
 mov  bh, 0     ;Display page 0
 mov  ah, 02h   ;Set Cursor
 int  10h
 push dx

 mov  dx, String
 mov  ah, 09h
 int  21h

 !!! Here you wait a bit !!!

 pop  dx
 mov  ah, 02h   ;Set Cursor
 int  10h

 mov  dx, White
 mov  ah, 09h
 int  21h
 ret


 String db 'Title', '$'
 White  db '     ', '$'
```